# Follow up on the Cloud Firestore Android codelab about performance

Tags: performance, filter, google-cloud-firestore

After doing the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) I have a few questions.

how many `document` can be stored under the `restaurants` collection and still
keep a quick filter search response? More specifically for example if the codelab was changed so instead searching for restaurants one would search and filter on stars in our galaxy. I know Cloud Firestore is real time but what if the collection holds one billion stars and to filter on things like size, location and spectral types.

Should One choose another approach for doing the star collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe is actually what Cloud Firestore was meant for. From the [announcement blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/introducing-cloud-firestore.html):

> Queries scale with the size of your result set, not the size of your
>   data set, so you'll get the same performance fetching 1 result from a
>   set of 100, or 100,000,000.

[Cloud Datastore has this property](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview), too. Our documentation on [structuring data in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data) might be helpful as well.

Comment: This is grate news I actually tried doing this with Firebase real time database but it was hard to create queries.